# extract scanned image data using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-processing, extract, getimagedata

Hello I am facing a problem, I have a form which have multiple questions, boolean questions and questions which have answers in text fields.

User will fill the form, scan it and upload it to node.js server. the node server will identify answer of multiple question and boolean question and save the user answer in database. and for the text fields crop that part and upload to storage server.

I have never worked on images, so do not have any idea where to start. Kindly guide me. I need your guidance very badly. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I strongly believe that the thing you need is Formdata, which could help transfer the image file into the hex data and store it in the data base.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: Problem is
User will create a template of exam which have
- Multiple choice questions
- Some boolean questions (true/false)
- Some text questions with text answers 

It will take print of that template, fill it, scan it and upload to node server.

Now the problem is to identify the selected answers of multiple choice questions, boolean questions and save the selected option in database.

For text questions snip the answer part and save it in database. 

I do not know how to perform this in node.js. I badly need help. Thank you :)